# Regression testing Issue [make installcheck]

Tags: postgresql, makefile, postgresql-extensions

#### For the regression tests:

##### The code for the makefile is:

```
EXTENSION = my_extension
DATA = my_extension--1.0.sql
REGRESS = my_extension--regress.sql

PG_CONFIG  ?= pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
include $(PGXS)
```

##### Regression testing SQL file `my_extension--regress.sql`:

```sql
-- regression test script for my_extension

-- Create the my_table table
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

-- Test the my_function function
SELECT my_function();

-- Verify the data in the my_table table
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

After running `make installcheck` on `my_extension` getting error:

Tried to set the environment variable PGUSER
`PGUSER=postgres make installcheck`

Got the error:

```sql
echo "+++ regress install-check in  +++" && /Users/spartacus/.pgenv/pgsql-15.0/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../src/test/regress/pg_regress --inputdir=./ --bindir='/Users/spartacus/.pgenv/pgsql-15.0/bin'    --dbname=contrib_regression my_extension--regress
+++ regress install-check in  +++
(using postmaster on Unix socket, default port)
============== dropping database "contrib_regression" ==============
SET
DROP DATABASE
============== creating database "contrib_regression" ==============
CREATE DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
============== running regression test queries        ==============
test my_extension--regress        ... diff: /Users/spartacus/Desktop/GSoC/CODE/my_extension/expected/my_extension--regress.out: No such file or directory
diff command failed with status 512: diff  "/Users/spartacus/Desktop/GSoC/CODE/my_extension/expected/my_extension--regress.out" "/Users/spartacus/Desktop/GSoC/CODE/my_extension/results/my_extension--regress.out" > "/Users/spartacus/Desktop/GSoC/CODE/my_extension/results/my_extension--regress.out.diff"
make: *** [installcheck] Error 2
```

Link to the Github issue: https://github.com/IshaanAdarsh/Postgres-extension-tutorial/issues/15 (for more details and the extension code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide `expected/my_extension--regress.out` so that the regression tests have something to compare the actual results with.

Typically, you proceed like this:

- run the regression tests and get the error message you see
- look at `results/my_extension--regress.out` and see if the output is as it should be
- if you are happy with the results, copy `results/my_extension--regress.out` to `expected/my_extension--regress.out`